# Dropdown list inside gridview binding for alternate rows on Rowdatabound

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, rowdatabound

I have `DropdownList` inside `gridview`in   `EditTemmplate` which I am binding on `RowDatabound`. But DropdlownList is binding for alternate rows only. For Example, For first row its binding, not for 2nd, for 3rd it is, and so on. Below is my code:

```
 Protected Sub grvTdsMaster_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grvTdsMaster.RowDataBound
    Try
        lblErrorMsg.Visible = False
        lblErrorMsg.InnerText = ""
        If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

            If ((e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit)) Then
                Dim ddlSection As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ddlSection")
                Dim objTds As New TdsMasterDL
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt = objTds.GetTdsSectionName()
                ddlSection.DataSource = dt
                ddlSection.DataValueField = "TDS_Section_Id"
                ddlSection.DataTextField = "TDS_Section_Name"
                ddlSection.DataBind()

            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Additional info that could be useful for debugging error
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        sb.Append("User=" & Session("username"))

        ExceptionHandler(ex, sb.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Are all rows in `Edit` mode?

Comment: Yeah, I debugged, for alternate rows, condition is false, but why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `RowState` is alternate by default. Check DataControlRowState Enum on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowstate(VS.80).aspx). This should work for you:-

```
If ((e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)Then
```

Comment: I had used same, it showed me null reference error. Still i will check again.Will get back to you